# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException | vb.net

Tags: vb.net, com, crystal-reports, comexception

I know this question has been answered many times but I have tried all previous suggested resolution.

1.) The target CPU is x86

2.) I have registered the ocx and dll files

The application is working fine on old machines (all OS) but not on new images.

Here is the log :

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated
>   due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(System.Guid
>   ByRef, System.Object, Int32, System.Guid ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(System.String,
>   System.Guid)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(System.Guid)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()    at
>   Restaurant.frmMain.InitializeComponent()    at
>   Restaurant.frmMain..ctor()
>
> Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException    at
>   Restaurant.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]    at
>   Restaurant.frmMain.Main()

Here is how I am registering the files :

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Caspol -q -machine -addgroup 1 -url file://C:/xyz/* FullTrust -name "V Drive"

regsvr32   c:\xyz\crystl32.ocx

regsvr32   c:\xyz\MSCOMCT2.OCX

regsvr32   c:\xyz\MSDATGRD.OCX

regsvr32   c:\xyz\cpeaut32.dll

regsvr32   c:\xyz\msstdfmt.dll

Crystal reports runtime engine for .NET 4 framework in installed on the system (both x86 and x64).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once.

`I ran Visual Studio as administrator. 
 Also make sure you know which setting your platform is for the build: AnyCPU, x86, x64`

For you its x86 so try using AnyCPU!

Try debugging the issue 
I read an article from Microsoft which said you can debug where this exception is occurring by:

`Debug > Exceptions... and use the Find option to locate System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. Tick the option to break when it's thrown and then debug your application.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JT4U. The application works fine on my dev machine. It's not working when deployed to one of our test servers.

Comment: if you find the answer useful. please upvote. so the next member who is stuck can use this issue. thank you! @DeependraSingh

Comment: unfortunately your suggestion hasn't resolved my problem. I have tried this before but I never get any errors on my dev machine. It occurs only when I deploy the code.

Comment: are you deploying the code using the proper build platform?

Comment: Yes. We have been copying the same code to user machines. After copying, we register the ocx files and it runs fine. Lately we have started having this problem with users on new machines.